# E-bike rims: can I use them on my touring bike?

Tags: rims, touring, electric-bike

I am touring with my MTB, now for 4 months.
I have been using really good Pacenti 29er rims, but just 2 days ago I cracked the rear one.
I am carrying a lot of weight and Pacenti (after I contacted them, great guys) made me notice that the rim even if strong for MTB is not made to carry that load.

I am thinking to replace the rims with E-bike ones, because they are actually made for heavier bikes.

Do you think it is a good idea?
The rim I would like to use is a:
DT SWISS Rim 545d 700c 28'' black 622-19 vl 6,5mm 36 hole simply eyed

Comment: Why not just use a touring specific rim?

Answer (score 5):

Does that rim state a load? How heavy are you touring? Not much of the strength of a wheel come from the rim anyway, at least as regards vertical loading. MTB touring can put extra shock loads on a wheel compared to road touring.

A rear e-bike rim has a lot of stress on it, and not just from the unsprung mass of a hub motor but the shorter spokes. So it might be good, but the actual load could easily be less than a loaded tourer.

The e-bike I've ridden is about 30kg bare. That's less than the *luggage* when I went bike camping. The rider is almost always the heaviest part of the system.

The toughest wheels are probably those built for touring tandems. 40 spokes are common, 48 not unknown.

Comment: Thank you Chris, I am carrying around 45kg. I think that e-bike rims might do the trick. I spoke with some rims manufarcturer and they gave me an idea of why it broke. Some extra strenght shouldnbe enough. Of course what youbare saying about tandem wheels is verybtrue, and it is what they said, but I don't want to change hubs too and go too expensive.

Comment: As well, can I use normal spokes on a ebike rim?

Comment: You might be able to find a 36 hole tandem rim, or a 36 hole version of a rim that also comes in 40+ holes. Ebike spokes are similar to touring spokes (thicker than some others) but shorter; the holes in the rim are the same

Comment: What did they say about why it broke? Did some spokes go as well?

Comment: This might be obvious, but 45kg is **a lot**. Try to reduce it, it makes touring much more enjoyable. Much of it is probably expendable, all cyclists with such heavy loads I’ve encountered carried stuff like hammers, bags of batteries, whole rolls of duct tape, changes of clothing for a whole week (i.e. 7 complete sets of clothing), bottles of wine …

Comment: @Michael, you're not wrong, but it depends on the tour. For example a photography tour by bike is a very different thing to a bike tour with a camera, and much heavier. Or an unsupported tour away from a water source for a few days gets heavy very fast indeed. That's why I class my 35kg trip as bike camping - I had hiking boots, wetsuit, and a bottle of wine in that load, but only rode 2x35km with it all on.

Comment: @Michael all the above is true, sometimes we carry a bottle, some others we carry food for 2 or 3 meals. I have a few tools, just minor things (no hammers), spare chain, quick release axles. We are travelling for some time, moving from a place to another in the south of Europe and the weather we have encountered in the past 4 months from Estonia, now Italy, then France is very different. We camp as well.

Comment: I built several wheels in my life and with not too bad results.
The weight we carry is actually quite needed.

Comment: @ChrisH Pacenti was very helpful. They eplained to me the difference between a strong MTB rim and another for touring or tandem that can withstand the weight. Otherwise they spoke as well about how DT swiss over build MTB rims, so it might work.

Comment: @ChrisH then looking on websites I realized that Ebiks rims are made for heavier MTBing and that it could do the job

Comment: As my e-bike experience is far from MTB, I'll defer to the manufacturers on that.  you may however want to edit into your question the type of terrain you're riding, as often when MTBs are used for touring the trails are fairly benign